# Como permitir duplicar valor de uma chave no SQL?

Tags: sql, query

Preciso que as chaves **Numero_Processo** e **Numero_Revisao**, possam receber valores que ja existem na tabela.
por exemplo:

```
Id = 1, Numero_Processo = 1, Numero_Revisao = 1
Id = 2, Numero_Processo = 1, Numero_Revisao = 2
Id = 2, Numero_Processo = 1, Numero_Revisao = 3
```

ou

```
Id = 4, Numero_Processo = 2, Numero_Revisao = 1
Id = 2, Numero_Processo = 2, Numero_Revisao = 2
Id = 2, Numero_Processo = 2, Numero_Revisao = 3
```

Em ambos os casos eu preciso repeti os valores Numero_Processo e Numero_Revisao.
Esses campos são chaves em outras tabelas com a tabela de Qualidade_Insp_Inj_Entrada na imagem abaixo .

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pelo que entendi na verdade você precisa utilizar uma chave composta (id, numero_processo, numero_revisao). Primeiro você precisa ver se está como `identity`  a sua chave atual.

Comment: Esse `id` também precisa repetir? Ele é a pk da tabela?

Comment: Uma chave estrangeira necessariamente precisa ser uma chave única na tabela de referência. Você precisará escolher uma outra chave na tabela que seja única (`id, numero_processo, numero_revisao`, por exemplo) e alterar a sua chave estrangeira para este novo registro único.

Comment: Meu Id é unico, não precisa repeti. Mas os campos Numero_Processo e Numero_Revisao eu preciso que seja chave e que aceite valores repetidos. Como fazer?

Comment: tem que ser chave estarangeira, e não chave primária, remova `PK_Numero_Processo` e `PK_Numero_Revisao`

Comment: *"Meu Id é unico, não precisa repeti. Mas os campos Numero_Processo e Numero_Revisao eu preciso que seja chave e que aceite valores repetidos"* @DanielleArrudatorres a tabela só pode ter uma chave primária, se o campo `ID` já é,  você pode usar os outros campos como chaves estrangeiras e repetir sem problema

Comment: @RovannLinhalis tem razão, não é uma chave primária obrigado por observar, remover o comentário que ficou sem propósito

Answer (score 0):

O problema parece ser por estar repetindo o mesmo valor no campo Id e não nos campos Numero_Processo e Numero_Revisao.
Você realmente não pode ter mais uma PK, mas você pode ter uma PK composta.

Existem três possíveis cenários:

- Você utiliza um Id diferente para cada linha e mantém a PK como está, neste caso ele iria aceitar.
- Caso seja possível repetir o Id, mas nunca repetir a combinação dos três campos, neste caso faria uma PK composta.

  ALTER TABLE [Qualidade_Insp_Inj_Processo] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Qualidade_Insp_Inj_Processo] PRIMARY KEY (Id, Numero_Processo, Numero_Revisao)
- Modelar suas tabelas de uma forma diferente, neste caso seria necessário conhecer melhor o projeto para poder sugerir essas mudanças.

Valeu o/